# Spatial linear regression: apply regression's model parameters at another spatial scale

Tags: r, linear-regression, raster, coefficients

I have two raster layers and I want to perform linear regression (LR). The first raster has 500m pixel size (called *ntl.tif*) and the other has 100m (called *tirs.tif*). In order to perform LR I need to aggregate the *tirs* to match the spatial resolution of *ntl*. After that I can perform LR and I can use the `predict` function at the coarse spatial scale.

My question is this: How can I apply the model parameters (*intercept* and *slope*) to predict at the fine spatial scale? What I mean is, I want to use the function `predict` so I can create the *lm_pred* raster (see code below) and not by typing the coefficients manually like I do. I know I need to check that the names (band names) of the raster from which the model was fitted should be the same as the names of the raster to which the model will be applied, but I can't figure it out how I can do that: This is what I am doing so far:

```
library(terra)

ntl = rast("path/ntl.tif") # coarse resolution raster

tirs = rast("path/tirs.tif") # fine resolution raster

tirs_res <- resample(tirs, ntl, method="bilinear")

s = c(ntl, tirs_res)

names(s) = c("ntl", "tirs")

model <- lm(formula = ntl ~ tirs, data = s)

lm_pred = model$coefficients[1] + model$coefficients[2] * tirs
```

If I use the `predict` function:

```
p = predict(tirs, model)
```

I am getting this error: `Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : object is not a matrix. In addition: Warning message:'newdata' had 1377 rows but variables found have 1008 rows`

Here's my dataset:

```
ntl = rast(ncols=272, nrows=200, nlyrs=1, xmin=12662503.7366, xmax=12798503.7366, ymin=3532049.3009, ymax=3632049.3009, names=c('ntl'), crs='EPSG:3857')

tirs = rast(ncols=1377, nrows=1008, nlyrs=1, xmin=12662000, xmax=12799700, ymin=3531700, ymax=3632500, names=c('B10_median'), crs='EPSG:3857')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `predict` to apply that fitted model to any raster you want. You just need to check that the names (band names) of the raster from which the model was fitted are the same as the names of the raster to which the model will be applied.

```
library(terra)
lm_pred010 <- predict(pop, model)
```